# Eclipse juno Egit error

Tags: android, egit, eclipse-juno

I am getting this error while starting my eclipse Juno

> EGit does not require Git to function, but there may be important settings in the installation directory that EGit needs to know about in order to be compatible with Git. The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for windows by default sets this parameter to true in the etc directory of the Git installation.
>
> The directory can be configured in Preferences under Team > Git.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:
1. Window > Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration > System Settings Tab
2. Use the Browse button and point to Git's global settings. In my case, that was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig`. I am running on a 64-bit Windows 7 but somehow my Git installation was under the 32-bit Program Files (x86).

Note: Eclipse will pick up the correct configuration even if you navigate just to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git.

Long Answer (this is from the [EGit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Setting_up_the_Home_Directory_on_Windows)):
**Pointing out the System wide configuration**

If you use Git for Windows as a companion to EGit, make sure EGit knows where Git is installed so it can find the "system wide settings", e.g. how core.autocrlf is set. Go to the settings and look under Team>Git>Configuration and then the System Settings tab.

If you selected one of the options to use Git from the Command Line Prompt when you installed Git for Windows, then the location of the system wide settings is filled in with a path and everything is fine. If not, use the Browse button to locate where Git is installed, e.g. C:\Program Files(x86)\Git.

This advice also applies to users of other Git packagings, e.g. Git under Cygwin or TortoiseGit.

Non-Windows users should in theory check this setting, but the system wide settings are usually not used on non-Windows platforms.